# How to Block barcode value to TextBox but barcode scanner still can use..?

Tags: jquery, barcode

i am going to make POS system. when use the barcode scanner it write the code in any text box that has focused.

***how to avoid that.
in other word i want to get barcode input from back side.where ever user has focused in the window, without write on focused element.

i used the http://a.kabachnik.info/jquery-scannerdetection-tutorial.html
my try as follow :

```
$(document).on('focus click', 'input', function(e){

        var clickedEleID = $(this).attr('id');
        $('#'+clickedEleID).unbind();//prevent other eval function trigger
        $(document).scannerDetection({
                timeBeforeScanTest: 100, 
                startChar: [120], 
                endChar: [13], 
                avgTimeByChar: 30, 
                onComplete: function(barcode, qty){ 

                $('#item_barcode').val(barcode);//where the right place, barcode should be display

                $('#'+clickedEleID).val(null);//focused element will clear
                $('#'+clickedEleID).bind();//again bind the other eval
                }
        });
```

});

Note:barcode reader fire keyevent "13" . my application has function for key event "13" to add bill information to data base. so i  added here

> $('#'+clickedEleID).unbind();

Comment: i found this example but it also unable to avoid the barcode value automatically appear if the textbox is focused.:https://codepen.io/krissco/pen/XdywLo

Answer (score 0):

You can use an option parameter to control this behavior.

Use this if you don't want the value to appear on any text box

```
 ignoreIfFocusOn: 'input'
```

Another way would be to add a class (something like 'scannerOff') to all the input fields that you want to be ignored, and then use the below option

```
ignoreIfFocusOn: '.scannerOff'
```

Comment: ignoreIfFocusOn: 'input'  ignore the barcode value also. but i want to catch it from background process to display it in another text box later. Thank you.